# I am trying to use this api. But I don't know where I am doing mistake. Am I using multple cookies in correct way or there is any other way

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is what I have tried till now and not getting where am I making mistake.

companyLink = 'https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/identity/profiles/';

let cookies = "cookie1=nj9ucrk32lohmd89mbuab5mjra79t61o8c3u8bgl;
cookie2=ae0f5d277f1255f7cf869fcf2bf914;cookie3=ae0f5d277f1255f7cf869fcf2bf914"

```
    async function fetchDetails(){
    try{
    const response = await fetch(companyLink,{
    method:'POST',
    credentials: "include",
    headers:{
    'Cookie': cookies,
    "Content-type":"multipart/form-data"
    }
    });
    
    const data = await response.formData();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
    }
   catch(error){
   console.log(error);
   }
   }
   fetchDetails().then(data=>{
   console.log(data);
   })
```

Comment: Thank you for your response...It is already in the background script

Comment: `fetch` can't send cookies, it's a [forbidden header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name). You can use `chrome.cookies` API or chrome.declarativeNetRequest so patch the outgoing headers.

Comment: okay @wOxxOm I will try these methods...Thank you
Also can you suggest me how I can learn chrome extention development. what topics should I cover and resources to learn them